# MySQL: Create all the rows where at least one attribute belongs

Tags: mysql, sql, join, relational-database

I have the tables

```
a (id INT, name VARCHAR(100))
b (id INT, name VARCHAR(100))
a_b (a INT, b INT)
```

I want to construct a query to get all the b's where a.name is equal to 'bob' but also include all the a's that have the same b.id as the b.ids found with the a.name.

For example,

```
a:                b:                 a_b:
id | name         id | name          a | b
_________________ _________________  _________
 1 | 'bob'         1 | 'dark'        1 | 1
 2 | 'tony'        2 | 'light'       1 | 2
 3 | 'steve'       3 | 'neg'         2 | 1
 4 | 'elon'        4 | 'elon'        3 | 1
```

So, I need all the b's with a.name = 'bob'

```
SELECT * FROM a_b
JOIN a ON a.id = a_b.a
JOIN b ON b.id = a_b.b
WHERE a.name = 'bob'
```

This gets the rows for when b.id = 1 and 2 but I also want all the a.names for when a b.id is the same. Ideally I want it to return

```
a's 1,2,3. b:1
a's 1 b: 2
```

So all the b's where at least one of the a's name attribute is equal to 'bob'
Is there any way to do this in SQL, or would I have to get all the rows and do the filtering operation in a programming language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work joining back to the `a_b` table and using `GROUP_CONCAT`:

```
SELECT b.id, group_concat(c.a) a
FROM a_b
  JOIN a ON a.id = a_b.a
  JOIN b ON b.id = a_b.b
  JOIN a_b c on b.id = c.b
WHERE a.name = 'bob'
GROUP BY b.id
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/45d48/1)